# Has anybody found out how to correctly autoindent .ejs in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, ejs, visual-studio-code

Has anybody figured out how to have VS Code correctly auto-format .ejs files?  I've followed the tips in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069089/ejs-formatting-in-vs-code), but nothing seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the users in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588140/ejs-formatting-in-vscode) was looking for such a way as well. The answer seems to be:

1. Install `EJS language support` plugin
2. Now you have ejs support, highlighting, and snippets, but some tags like

```html
    <? for( let item of array ) { ?>
    (some data)
    <? } ?>
```

are formatted incorrectly (at least with default html formatter).

3. To fix this, you can try set custom delimeter to '?' `ejs.delimeter = '?'`. Now you have correct indentation with `<? ... ?>` tags.
4. To use the snippets with our custom delimeter, you need to edit extension snippets (or add your own): install `Snippets Ranger` plugin, then find needed extension and edit its file. The `Snippets Ranger` is very handy tool.

User [Victor Gorban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9047572/victor-gorban) seems to be used to doing this so reaching out to him wouldn't be a bad idea.